# Basic PHP function result in html table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I'm just trying some very basic PHP here. Trying to show the results of a function in an HTML table. For some reason, the results wont sit inside the `<td>` tags where they should be, any help be brilliant... What am I doing wrong?

```
<body>
  <?php
    $days = array("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday");

    function sayDay($x){
        global $days;
        print "Today is $days[$x]";
    }

    echo '<table border="1"><tr><th>Day of Week</th></tr>
    <tr><td>'.sayDay(0).'</td></tr><tr><td>'.sayDay(1).'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>'.sayDay(2).'</td></tr><tr><td>'.sayDay(3).'</td></tr>
    <tr><td>'.sayDay(4).'</td></tr>
    </table>';
  ?>
</body>
```

Comment: what does it print out? cannot find problem so far

Comment: You are echoing and the function is printing.  Try `return "Today is $days[$x]";`

Comment: The current output would help to debug. Can you provide it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should `return` not `print`.

Comment: Hey Sorry, thanks a million, it worked when, i changed my function to return rather than print.. before that it was just printing out the 5 days in a line above the table

Answer (score 2):

`print` prints immediatelly. `return` returns its value to where it is needed.

```
  function sayDay($x){
                global $days;
                return "Today is $days[$x]";
            }
```

Comment: You've got over 8K reputation. You should know that dumping code into an answer without explaining anything isn't very helpuful. Please explain what you changed and why it works.